# NodeJS post request not posting the fields but posts headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm trying to post variable to a website using node.js and the request module.

It's posting the headers but when I print the response.body it shows the fields to be empty.

The data I need is in the headers but the headers don't contain the data because the fields arn't being posted.

Here is my code, I only started node.js a few hours ago but I'm not new to JS.

```
    var request = require('request'); 
request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/login',
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Chocolate 2.0 XD",   
    },
    user_id: "some user",
    password: "some pass",
    storecookie: 'on',
    checkerrors: 'yes',
},function(error, response,body){
    if(error){
    console.log(error);
    } else if(response.statuscode !== 200) {
    console.log(response.body);   
    }
});
```

What do you think could be the problem?

I specified the URL, the return transfer and all the params.

Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `formData` if you are sending out post parameters.

```
var request = require('request'); 
request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/login',
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Chocolate 2.0 XD",   
    },
    formData: {
        user_id: "some user",
        password: "some pass",
        storecookie: 'on',
        checkerrors: 'yes'
    }
},function(error, response,body){
    if(error){
    console.log(error);
    } else if(response.statuscode !== 200) {
    console.log(response.body);   
    }
});
```

More info in docs: https://github.com/request/request#forms

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I just tried the formData but to no avail! Any other suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: as far as I know, this should work in normal cases, there might be some tricks if the server that you are sending the data to is doing something tricky!

Comment: Ahh perfect, added the checkerrors and store cookie inside the formData and it works like a charm :) Thank you much!

Comment: glad that it helped. I edited my answer just for future references.

Comment: consider marking this as the answer for future visitors :)

Comment: Not a problem :) Need to wait 3mins haha.